# Make Wine and Mono command-line invocations play well together on Debian?

Tags: debian, mono, wine

I'm on Debian 12 (Bookworm).  I have had Mono installed (from https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian, to run Duplicati backup software) for years.  I'm trying to get Wine working smoothly.

Wine works well enough when invoked directly: `wine hello.exe` does the right thing.  But I can't run `hello.exe` directly from the command line.

I did `sudo apt install wine-binfmt` to get the Wine binary-format handlers installed.  But still:

```
$ ./hello.exe
Cannot open assembly './hello.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
```

I think that's because I've got two handlers registered for MS-DOS ("MZ" executables "4d5a"):

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/cli
enabled
interpreter /usr/lib/binfmt-support/run-detectors
flags:
offset 0
magic 4d5a
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/wine
enabled
interpreter /usr/lib/binfmt-support/run-detectors
flags:
offset 0
magic 4d5a
```

Oh, but they both point to `run-detectors` as the handler, which ... stores its config files in /usr/share/binfmts/ ... and I've got two overlapping handlers in there:

```
$ cat /usr/share/binfmts/cli
package mono-runtime
detector /usr/lib/cli/binfmt-detector-cli
interpreter /usr/bin/cli
magic MZ
$  cat /usr/share/binfmts/wine
package wine
interpreter /usr/bin/wine
magic MZ
```

The `cli` command is Mono (`readlink -f /usr/bin/cli` => `/usr/bin/mono-sgen`).  I assume the Mono "binaries" that `cli` expects are .NET bytecode packaged to look like an MS-DOS binary?  Is there some "detector" I can install that disambiguates a Mono binary from a "regular" MS-DOS binary and sends one kind to Mono and one kind to Wine?

Comment: /usr/lib/cli/binfmt-detector-cli is supposed to disambiguate these kinds of binaries (its the "detector" filter in the "cli" entry).  Its not working in my setup....

Comment: It seems like PE binaries built by Zig look like "CLI" binaries to the detector.  So maybe a different problem....

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/756171/can-mono-and-wine-be-used-in-the-same-os-what-are-the-side-effects-of-using-bot/756176#756176

Comment: The question is a better fit for [unix.se] anyway, voting to migrate it.

Answer (score 1):

The current `/usr/lib/cli/binfmt-detector-cli` has a bug and classifies most PE32+ binaries as "CLR" (i.e., for Mono).  Before May 2022 the classifier has a bug where all PE32+ binaries were classified as native.  See https://github.com/mono/linux-packaging-mono/pull/38.

Fixing the classifier to correctly classify PE32+ binaries as CLR or not fixes my problem (the rest of the Wine/Mono stack and the wine-binfmt all work as intended).